# jQuery - calling function variable from another function variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't this work:

```
  var foo = function() {
     ...
  };

  var boo = function() {
     ... 
     el.foo();
   }
```

?

I get a foo is undefined error. But I just defined it above...

Comment: Call it: `foo()` instead of `el.foo()`

Comment: I'm guessing there's some important context we're missing. `el.foo()` doesn't work here because (from what I can see) you don't create `foo` as a method of the object `el` - you create a normal variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call foo(), not el.foo().  (Unless I'm missing something about how you're using this.)

Answer (score 3):

Since foo is not a function defined/attached to el hence you can't call foo from el's context.
You need to call foo directly.

```
  var foo = function() {
     ...
  };

  var boo = function() {
     ... 
     foo();
   }
```

However if you need to call foo attached to el's context then try this:

```
var boo = function() {
         ... 
         foo.call(el);//This calls foo in el's context
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you need to create a jQuery plugin function:

```
jQuery.fn.foo = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        // element-specific code here
    });
};

var boo = function() {
     ... 
     el.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `foo` isn't a property of `el`. It's a variable.

You'd need:

```
var foo = function() {
   //...
};

var boo = function() {
   //... 
   foo();
}
```

It would work if you had:

```
var el = {};
el.foo = function() {
    // ...
};

var boo = function() {
   //... 
   el.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this instance it looks like `foo()` is a not a property of the object `el`.  You defined the function, but from the example shown, it is probably a global function.  If you want `foo()` to work on the variable `el`, then pass it to the function, like so:

```
 var foo = function(element) {
     //do something with this element
  };

 var boo = function() {
     ... 
     foo(el); //pass el into the foo function so it can work on it.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume, if you are trying to call:

```
 el.foo()
```

Then el is jQuery object, something like

```
 var el = $("#smth");
 el.foo();
```

In this case you need to define 'foo' as:

```
$.fn.foo = function() {
....
}
```

Otherwise, if you are just trying to call 'foo' from 'boo', then just call it without 'el':

```
var foo = function() {
 ...
};

var boo = function() {
  ... 
  foo();
}
```

Hope, it helps.